# ManageOverflow for BorderLayout EXTJS

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, extjs4.1, border-layout

I would like to know if manageOverflow is working for a viewport with a border layout.
My app have a viewport (border layout) and inside 4 containers (2 North, 1 east and 1 west). One of these containers (the one on the east) is my main container with a layout fill.
When I "change my page", I dynamically fill this main containers with my page container.

My problem is : when I put a grid container whitch is longer than my innerHeight (screen size), a vertical scrollbar appear, which is good, but also an horizontal scrollbar. The viewport doesn't auto relayout with the new size (the size without the scrollbar).

The manageOverflow seems to be the answer but when I add this properties to my layout, it's the same result as the property reserveScrollbar.

Anyone had already tried this ?

Edit : some code for test : 
`

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>test</title>


    <script src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/ext-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        Ext.application({

            name: 'test',
            launch: function() {

                Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                    layout: {
                        type: 'border',
                        manageOverflow: 1
                    },

                    autoScroll:true,

                    items : [{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        region: 'north',
                        height: 150,
                        border: 5,
                        style: {
                            borderColor: 'black',
                            borderStyle: 'solid'
                        }
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        region: 'west',
                        width: 150,
                        border: 5,
                        style: {
                            borderColor: 'green',
                            borderStyle: 'solid'
                        }
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        region: 'north',
                        height: 150,
                        border: 5,
                        style: {
                            borderColor: 'red',
                            borderStyle: 'solid'
                        }                       
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'container',
                        region : 'center',
                        border: 5,
                        style: {
                            borderColor: 'blue',
                            borderStyle: 'solid'
                        }                       
                    }],
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body></body>
```

`

Comment: I did not try this but according to the docs (where you have a comment ;)) `manageOverflow` and `reserveScrollbar` are different things. The latter just puts a placeholder scrollbar inside the container and `manageOverflow` recalculates the layout if it gets overflowed.

Comment: Thanx for the answer.But it's because, according to the doc, it seems to be 2 different things but in my code, the layout is never recalculates... So I post this question to know if it's a bug or if it's just my code.